# Connect to OpenVPN on server but still allow SSH connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, openvpn, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup an openvpn client on my Google cloud Ubuntu 18.04 VM, which will encrypt outbound traffic to my VPN provider and obfuscate my public IP.

I have done this before on other providers and it requires a custom route for allowing SSH into my server while it's connected to VPN (so return packets don't get sent out the VPN tunnel).

this is the workaround i've used before:

ip rule add table 128 from VPS_PUBLICIP

ip route add table 128 to VPS_PUBLICIP

ip route add table 128 default via DEFAULT_GATEWAY

However i can't get it working on my GCP vm. This following file runs at startup, along with a ping to my server which verifies the VPN is connecting:

ip rule add table 128 from 34.70.149.123

ip route add table 128 to 34.70.149.123

ip route add table 128 default via 10.128.0.1

here is the output of route -n on the server beforehand:

Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface

0.0.0.0 10.128.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 100 0 0 ens4

10.128.0.1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 100 0 0 ens4

any help to get ssh routing correctly is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

By default a GCE instances cannot forward packets originated by another resource.

So, in order to change the above, I suggest to double check if the [IP forwarding feature](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward) is enabled for your instance.